# Post photos to an album using a batch request and curl

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-batch-request

I'm trying to post a number of photos to an already created album using `cURL` with the following command:

```
 curl -F 'access_token=<>' \
    -F 'batch=[ \
        {"method":"POST","relative_url":"/album_id/photos","url":"<photo_url>"}, \
        {"method":"POST","relative_url":"/album_id/photos","url":"<photo_url>"}]' \
        https://graph.facebook.com
```

The error I'm getting is `(#324) Requires upload file`. Is it even possible to post photos in a batch request to an album and if so what is the correct way to do it with `cURL`? Thanks!

Edit: the correct command thanks to CBroe is:

```
curl -F 'access_token=<>' \
     -F 'batch=[ \
         {"method":"POST","relative_url":"/album_id/photos","body":"url=<photo_url>"}, \
         {"method":"POST","relative_url":"/album_id/photos","body":"url=<photo_url>"}]' \
         https://graph.facebook.com
```

Comment: You need to specify the url parameter as part of the request body.

Comment: @CBroe The `url` is there in the request. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, that it belongs into the `body`, as the examples in the documentation show.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, missed that, thanks!